# Existence of a right adjoint to a functor

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

I am recently studying some topics on Category Theory and I am stuck with the adjoint functors (in this moment I decided to join Math SX).
I already know how to find a left or right adjoint, if it exists (usual free constructions etc.), but I find it challenging to prove that such adjoint functor does not exist.
In this case, I am asked to prove that there is no right adjoint at the forgetful functor from the category of commutative rings with unity to rings: 
 $F: \;\bf{CommRings} \to \bf{Rings}$
I already know some theorems, that state the conditions for a functor to have an adjoint (preserves limits, there exists an initial object in a category... etc), but I find it extremely difficult to understand, let alone apply them.

Comment: A particular case of left adjoints preserving colimits is that they preserve coproducts. Do you know the coproducts in these two categories?

Comment: I guess some sort of free products (I say this in analogy to the category of groups, which I understand better), but as I mentioned, everything about category theory is complicated for me.

Comment: Yes, the coproduct in rings is a kind of free product (on the multiplicative monoids) but for commutative rings, it is a tensor product, which can be viewed as a free product *subject to* the condition that elements from $a$ and from $b$ commute with each other. This is much like the distinction between coproducts of groups and of abelian groups.

Comment: I still fail to see how do we conclude that the right adjoint doesn't exist. Are we supposed to build some ring homomorphism from some product in CommRing and prove that it is not preserved? I really don't have the slightest idea how to solve this type of exercises, so apologize if nothing I saw makes any sense. Also, if there is any good book for beginners with solved exercises on Category Theory, could you please mention it? :)

Comment: No, just prove that the ring underlying the coproduct of two commutative rings is not a isomorphic to a coproduct of general rings. This doesn't involve any serious computation; for instance the tensor product of finite commutative rings is finite, but this never happens with noncommutative rings.